# jquery datatables doesn't show any data - json formatting error

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, datatable

I've got simple table

```
<table class="datatable table table-striped table-bordered" id="usertable">
                <thead>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

And here my javascript code. I want to send ajax request to spring controller and return data.

```
$(function() {
$('.datatable').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "bs_full",
    "sAjaxSource" : "loadusers.html",
    "aoColumns" : [
        {
            "sTitle" : "Name",
            "mData" : "name"
        },
        {
            "sTitle" : "Surname",
            "mData" : "surname"
        },
        {
            "sTitle" : "Username",
            "mData" : "username"
        }
     ]
});
$('.datatable').each(function(){
    var datatable = $(this);
    var search_input = datatable.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_filter] input');
    search_input.attr('placeholder', 'Search');
    search_input.addClass('form-control input-sm');
    var length_sel = datatable.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_length] select');
    length_sel.addClass('form-control input-sm');
});
});
```

In my spring controller I return data like this

```
@RequestMapping("/loadusers.html")
@ResponseBody 
public String test(Model model) {        
    //get list of users
    //get list of logins for users
    logger.debug("TRY TO RETURN AJAX RESPONSE");

    return "{  \"name\" : \"name1\", \"surname\" : \"surname1\", \"username\" : \"username1\" }";
}
```

but it doesn't work and I've got parsing error.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed several things and now it works just fine

Javascript

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "bs_full",
    "bProcessing" : true,
    "sAjaxSource" : "loadusers.html",
    "sAjaxDataProp" : "test"
});
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/loadusers.html")
@ResponseBody 
public String test(Model model) {        
    logger.debug("TRY TO RETURN AJAX RESPONSE");

    return "{ \"test\": [ "
            + "[ \"name1\", \"surname1\", \"username1\"],"
            + "[ \"name2\", \"surname2\", \"username3\"],"
            + "[ \"name2\", \"surname2\", \"username3\"]"
            + "] }";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested to Jackson mapper instead of returning a string of json. By setting

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer"/>
    </property>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

you can then return objects directly converted into json

```
@RequestMapping("/loadusers.html")
@ResponseBody 
public String test(Model model) {        
     // Compose your dataTable object
    return dataTable;
}
```

Obviously jackson should be imported. With maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```